# Why my regex does not work when using beginning and end of string anchors?

Tags: regex, validation, regex-lookarounds

I have developed the following regex trying to match a string with at least one digit and at least one lowercase character.

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)
```

This seems to be working OK. For example it matches 'abc3' and not 'abc'

However as soon as I modify the regex by adding the beginning and end of string anchors it stops working. Would you know why?

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)$
```

Comment: `$` is terminating the match..basically you are testing for a  lower case, a digit and empty string together which is not possible..use `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*$`..lookaheads are of zero width..they do not consume any characters

Comment: Explaining the above comments: the lookaheads *check* but they don't *consume* characters. So the only thing that gets actually matched is `^$` – an empty line. The lookaheads fail because cannot be anything "beyond" the end-of-string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is terminating the match here. So you are testing basically for a lowercase character and a digit (*which is ok*). As lookaheads are of zero width, current position of checking does not changes (*which by default here is in starting due to `^`*).

After checking lowercase and digit, you are basically left with `^$` regex which matches empty string (*remember the position of matching has not changed **because of zero-width property of lookahead***).

This is contradictory to your requirements (*because there is already a lowercase character and a digit. So string can never be empty. This is causing the regex to fail*)

You have to use

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).*$
```